# Get content of the php file

Tags: php, file, get

**How to get all the current code from one php-file inside other php-file?**

Like, we have file `a.php` with some functions inside.

And file `b.php`, where we want to get all the code (without running any functions) from `a.php` and echo it to the browser when requested.

**Like**
(inside `b.php`):

```
$content = get_all_file_text(a.php);
echo $content;
```

Thanks.

Comment: This seems simple enough, but unfortunately the browser will interpret `<?php` as the beginning of an HTML tag. Therefore, most of the solutions here will not work as it results in output that appears blank.

Comment: Pedantic note: it'll interpret `<?php` as a [XML Processing Instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) and ignore it...  But it should render any other html tags outside of the `<?php ?>` blocks fine...

Comment: @ircmaxell thanks for the clarification. All I was saying, I guess, is that unless you encode the PHP as HTML entities, the code will not be visible on the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

seems everyone so like file_get_contents, here is my suggestion as you try to output it to browser :

file_get_contents + highlight_string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

Answer (score 4):

This seems simple enough, but unfortunately the browser will interpret `<?php` as the beginning of an HTML tag.

To avoid this, you must use htmlentities on the PHP code. Also, to preserve formatting, the nl2br function.

c.php:

```
<?php
$f='snizz';
function plip($f){ echo $f; }
$r=array(1,2,3,32);
```

a.php:

```
<?php
$f=file_get_contents('c.php');
echo nl2br(htmlentities($f));
```

This will produce the correct output in the browser.

I like the answer with the highlight_string function, too.

Comment: Thanks buddy, still useful in 2018

Answer (score 2):

See this method:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

This gives you back a string that you can easily dish out to your clients.

Good day.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this page:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('b.php');
echo $file;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the file_get_contents() function. Check out www.php.net/file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

`readfile` will be simpler than `file_get_contents`

`readfile` reads the file and outputs it in one function, whereas `file_get_contents` reads it into a string which must then be outputted

[php.net/readfile](http://php.net/readfile)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code...

a.php

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://localhost/yourpath/b.php");
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php
 echo "HELLO WORLD!!!";
?>
```